# Question about mix marketing modeling (MMM)

Tags: regression, mixed-model, multiple-regression, modeling, marketing

I am working on multiple regression in order to realize a marketing mix model. However I have some concerns with the procedure. First, the idea of transforme data in order to incorporate the carryover effect : the intuition behind the carryover effect is clear however from what I have understood, the way to do it is unclear, I explain this now. Consider the model

$$
y_t = \beta_{0} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\beta_ix_{i,t} + \epsilon_{t}
$$

where $y_t$ is the sales volume of a company and the $x_{i}$'s some explanatory variables that correspond to channel media, price, distribution, etc..

The idea is to consider a variable $x_{i,t}$ that has been deployed in time $t$ with a carryover effect, that is, the variable has a kind of persistency for customers after time $t$ (one can think of a campaign TV for example) and include this persistency by considering a well-chosen transformation such that for the next period ($t+1$, $t+2$,...) the effect of the variable $x_{i}$ appears. My concern is the following : by doing that, we loose the equality in our model since we added some values for next periods that are not present in our initial data since $y_t$ has not changed ?

So I would like to know where I am wrong in my reasoning please in order to fully understand this concept.

Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Yt hasn't changed, but its explanation distribution has now changed via the transformed Xt values that are now going into the future. This added explanatory power will be picked up by the regression method and it means other variables other than Xt will have their own influence on Yt reduced, all else equal.